# Can't remove tabIndex from jquery tabs widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabwidget, tabindex

I have a simple jquery tab widget set up. It starts off with two tabs, one being error 1, one being a plus sign. Clicking the plus sign adds error 2 tab. Clicking it again adds error 3 tab. The problem is I can't remove the tab index from the tabs after I click the plus sign. RemoveAttr('tabIndex') works on page load to keep the first tab from having an index, but after I click the plus sign I haven't found a way to remove the tab indexes from the rest of the tabs. I put the removeAttr() right after .show(). I put it before that line. I tried putting it in activate, load, beforeload, and create. I've tried setting tabindex=-1 instead of removeattr(). I've also tried getting rid of hide/show and using css to display/not display.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.newTab.attr('id') == 'liTabsPlus') {
                event.preventDefault();
                errorTabsShowing += 1;
                $('#liTabs' + errorTabsShowing).show();
                $(this).tabs('option', 'active', errorTabsShowing - 1);
                if (errorTabsShowing == MAX_NUMBER_OF_ERRORS)
                    ui.newTab.hide();
            }
        }
    });

    $("#liTabs1").removeAttr("tabIndex");
    $("#liTabs2").hide();
    $("#liTabs3").hide();
    $("#liTabs4").hide();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove `tabindex`?

Comment: The tabindex attribute is used to control how the tab key on the end user's keyboard behaves. IS that what you intend? Please paste the relevant HTML in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FDKHee/yT5x5/1/, save and paste the resulting link here.

Comment: In your example code you have tabIndex in camelcase. Have you tried it all lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your markup but I've done this by looping through my elements and setting the tab index to -1. This would be an example for doing this with all tabs starting with the id of "liTabs" so liTabs1, liTabs23, etc.

```
$('[id^=liTabs]').each(function(){ this.tabIndex = -1; });
```

Hope this helps